# In HTML/JavaScript, is there a way to know an images final layout dimensions the moment the image starts loading?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a script that examines elements and makes all the elements equal the height of the tallest element of the set. This works fine except for when images take a while to load, because by then the heights have already been set.

To overcome this I added an onload listener to the img tag and after the image has completely loaded, it resets the height of everything correctly.

Now the problem is, if there is a particularly large image, or slow connection, things still look strange while the image is downloading.  Is there a way JavaScript can know the ultimate display height of the image at the BEGINNING of the download, rather than the end?

Comment: One way would be to get the image metadata from the server using an ajax call before downloding the images. What are you using for server side processing ? Can you post some code?

Comment: server side is unknown and so are the images to be received. This is for a library that could be used by anybody in any environment using any form of data-retrieval.

Comment: You may just have to delay formatting until all the images load and just show a loading spinner while it waits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
var bigImage = new Image();
bigImage.src = "path/to/image";
bigImage.onload = function() {
    //create image tag with dimensions and insert into dom
    console.log(bigImage.width, bigImage.height);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still require the image to download completely until the width and height are known?

Comment: Oh, i think i see. You're saying add it to the dom after downloaded. That might work.

Comment: Ya. It would , But your document can first load without the image tags. And your js can then update the document with the computed image sizes

Comment: Yes, the onload won't fire until it is finished.